# Getting a sub-string from a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Is there a way in python to extract each substring thats inside a string?

For example if I have the string

```
"Hello there my name is Python"
```

I want to take out each sub-string (or individual word) from within this string so that I have `"Hello", "there" , "my" , "name" , "is"` and `"Python"` each taken out of this string?

Comment: You should at least have searched. `str.split` is what you want

Comment: `a = "Hello there my name is Python"` and then `b = a.split()`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

It will break the string with specified delimeter. Default delimeter is a space.

```
input_string = "Hello there my name is Python" 
for substring in input_string.split():
    print(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split()` string method.

```
>>> sentence = 'Hello there my name is Python'
>>> words = sentence.split()
>>> print words
['Hello', 'there', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Python']
```